# Lifetime does not live long enough

Tags: rust

There is a code that produces the following error:

```rust
fn foo<'a, F1, F2>(f: F1)
    where
        F1: FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> F2,
        F2: FnOnce() + 'a,
{
    let mut a = 0;
    f(&mut a)();
}

fn main() {
    foo(|a| {
        || {
            *a += 1;
            ()
        }
    });
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:7
  |
1 | fn foo<'a, F1, F2>(f: F1)
  |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
7 |     f(&mut a)();
  |     --^^^^^^-
  |     | |
  |     | borrowed value does not live long enough
  |     argument requires that `a` is borrowed for `'a`
8 | }
  | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I'm very confused because error message says that `a` is still borrowed but `foo` returns nothing!

Comment: You don't use `F2`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what do you mean? It's used as return type for `F1` at 3rd line and called at 7th line as well as `F1`

Comment: My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. a Lifetime issue
2. it tries to return a closure

## 1. The lifetime issue

You can reduce the example in your question to

```
fn foo<'a, F1>(f: F1)
where
    F1: FnOnce(&'a mut i32),
{
    let mut a = 0;
    f(&mut a);
}

fn main() {
    foo(|a| {
            *a += 1;
    });
}
```

and here you can probably see more clearly, that

```
fn foo<'a, F1>(f: F1)
where
    F1: FnOnce(&'a mut i32)
```

means, that the caller of `foo` can decide, what `'a`
will be.

But in

```
let mut a = 0;
f(&mut a);
```

you create `a`, which has its concrete lifetime (essentially
the body of `foo`) and try to call `f` with it. But `'a` which
the caller has chosen, doesn't need to have to do anything
with the lifetime of `a`, it can be wildly larger for example.

Worded differently

```
    fn foo<'a, F1>(f: F1)
    where
        F1: FnOnce(&'a mut i32)
```

means: If you call `foo` you can hand it something function
like `f` (function pointer, closure, ...), which needs its parameter
to live at least as long as `'a`. `'a` could be `'static`
for example.

So inside `foo` you can't just create a thing with its concrete
lifetime and hand if to `f`, as you don't know, what `'a` the
caller of `foo` will choose.

You might now be surprised, that

```
fn foo<F1>(f: F1)
    where
        F1: FnOnce(&mut i32),
{
    let mut a = 0;
    f(&mut a);
}

fn main() {
    foo(|a| {
            *a += 1;
    });
}
```

compiles just fine, but that is simply, because `foo` in this example desugars to

```
fn foo<F1>(f: F1)
    where
        F1: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32),
{
    let mut a = 0;
    f(&mut a);
}
```

which means, that not the caller of `foo` decides, what the lifetime `'a` will be, but `f` has to be something, that can work with a parameter of any lifetime. So `foo` can choose `'a` in this case.

But to be able to return anything, which has the lifetime `'a` chosen by `foo`, you would need to be able to write it into `foo`s signature, which you can't, to the best of my knowledge.

## 2. it tries to return a closure

The [Rust Book, "Returning Closures"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html#returning-closures) tells us, you can't
return closures.

But

```
fn returns_closure(a: &mut i32) -> impl FnMut() + '_ {
    || {
      *a += 1;
      println!("{}", *a);
    }
}

fn main() {
  let mut sum: i32 = 5;
  let mut f = returns_closure(&mut sum);
  f();
  f();

  let mut sum2: i32 = 10;
  let mut g = returns_closure(&mut sum2);
  g();
  g();
}
```

just works fine for me on rustc version 1.58.1.

The [Rust Book, "Returning Types that Implement Traits"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#returning-types-that-implement-traits) tells us that you can use the
`impl SomeTrait` syntax only in return types of functions and methods, which
always return the same concrete type on all function exits.

So the above syntax doesn't apply to closures.

But with generic types we can still do something similar.

```
fn foo<F1, F2>(f: &mut F1)
where
    F1: FnMut(i32) -> F2,
    F2: FnMut(),
{
    let mut g = f(1);
    g();
    g();
    let mut h = f(2);
    h();
    h();
}

fn main() {
    foo(&mut (|_a: i32| || println!("wtf")));
    foo(&mut (|_a: i32| {
        let mut a = 5;
        move || {
            a += 1;
            println!("wtf: {}", a);
        }
    }));
}
```

still works fine for me. So it seems as long as the compiler can
figure out the concrete types and the closure returning a closures
also always returns the same concrete type, it works for
rustc 1.58.1.

So my guess is, the syntax simply lacks. There needs to be
some syntax to write something like the following pseudo code:

```
fn foo<F1, F2>(f: &mut F1)
where
    F2: FnMut(),
    F1: for<'a> FnMut(&'a mut i32) -> F2 + 'a,
{
    ...
}
```

I guess the lifetime bound is part of the type at the moment and so
the caller, which chooses `F2` would need to know the required lifetime,
that gets choosen in the call ... but thats just guessing.

As the required lifetime bound shouldn't influence the size
needed for the closure returned by `f`,
something like that might be possible?

In

```
fn foo2<F1>(f: &mut F1)
where
    F1: for<'a> FnMut(&'a mut i32) -> Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>,
{
    ...
}
```

we can neatly express what we want at the unfortunate cost of allocating ...
But now `f` can of course return different closures with different types
wrapped up in the `Box`, so it is also more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I think reduced code you'd supposed is not fully correct since it may be fixed by removing `'a` lifetime, which doesn't work in my case. Looks like compiler can't infer appropriate lifetimes in complex cases, so we need to do it by ourselves.

Comment: If you remove the lifetime `'a`, `fn foo<F1>(f: F1) where F1: FnOnce(&mut i32)` desugars to `fn foo<F1>(f: F1) where F1: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32)`, which is something else. It means, you need to hand `foo` something function like, which can work with whatever lifetime its parameter will have, when it is called. I'll probably add this as a distinguishing example to my answer.

Comment: Yep, `where for` solution works, but only using `Box`. So, I was able to get this code compiling by changing`foo` bounds to `where for<'a> F: FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'a>` and wrapping `F2` closure in `main` into `Box`. Anyway this doesn't seems clear to me since we need to allocate heap memory every time we call `F1`. So, if you think there is no solution cleaner than using `Box`, add this code to your answer and I'll mark it as solution since your explanation of lifetimes is really great

Comment: Sorry, I can't come up with a solution avoiding `Box` at the moment. Please clarify your question. You just posted a piece of code and that you didn't understood the error the compiler was producing for it.
If you request the Box solution to be in the answer, then please formulate a question, to that this would be an answer.